# Clearing an Array in C++ Produces Compiler Error in external function but not in main( )

Tags: c++

For my program I am trying to give the user an option to clear an array (set every element to 0), I have the following code in the main function:

```
cout << "To clear a position, enter 'C' or 'c': ";
cin >> clear;

switch(clear) {
    case 'C':
    case 'c':
        cout << "What position would you like to clear? Enter the position or -1 to clear the entire array: ";
        cin >> clearPosition;
        clearElement (arr, SIZE, clearPosition);
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

and the following function:

```
void clearElement (int arr[ ], const int SIZE, int clearPosition) {
    if (clearPosition == -1)
        arr[SIZE] = {0};
    else
        arr[clearPosition - 1] = 0;
}
```

In the main function I declared:

```
int arr[SIZE] = {0};
```

with no problems, but when I try to use that same code in the function I get the error code:

```
arrayFunction.cpp: In function ‘void clearElement(int*, int, int)’:
arrayFunction.cpp:64:17: warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11
   arr[SIZE] = {0};
```

Does anybody know why I am able to assign {0} to my array in the declaration at the beginning of the main function, but I am unable to do it in my `clearElement( )` function?

Comment: You can use `std::array` and `std::fill` as an alternative.

Comment: A good solution is to avoid this whole problem in the first place, by not using raw pointers and separate length variables

Comment: `arr[SIZE] = { 0 }` attempts to set the element whose index is `SIZE` to `0`.

Answer (score 4):

`int arr[SIZE] = {0};` is array initialization syntax. It's only legal when you are declaring and initializing the array on the same line.

It's illegal in the function, because the array already exists. Outside the declaration line after all, `arr[SIZE]` is interpreted as trying to index the array, not size it.

For something like this, you can just use `memset`:

```
memset(arr, '\0', sizeof(arr[0]) * SIZE);
```

For a more C++-y way to do it, you can use:

```
std::fill(arr, arr+SIZE, 0);
```

Comment: `memset` should be avoided in C++

Comment: better would be `std::fill`

Comment: Yeah, I was just adding that. :-) That said, for POD `int`, `memset` is perfectly fine.

Comment: Regarding memset ;) https://isocpp.org/blog/2015/12/the-most-dangerous-function-in-the-c-cpp-world

Comment: Memset is fine.. until you want to set it to something other than 0, or change the type.

Comment: @vsoftco: Well, okay, it's no less fine than in C. The real gotcha with `memset` is more about arrays degrading to pointers in non-obvious ways. and the non-intuitive behavior of `sizeof` in the array vs. pointer case. The fact that `memset` happens to be the most common function to be screwed up by those issues says more about `memset`'s utility than it does anything else.

Comment: @NeilKirk: Agreed. The single case of zero-ing is what was asked for, and `memset` is essentially canonical there; for anything else, I'd have leapt for `std::fill`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Yes, that's true. What I found interesting though in the article is that one shouldn't use it for security-based work (i.e. zero-ing some "secret" memory), as it may be optimized out.

Comment: Ok you misunderstood me. I was saying memset is actually not fine because it breaks too easily when changes are made, as they will to a real project.

Comment: @NeilKirk: Didn't misunderstand, just accidentally deleted the bit that made it clear that I agreed with what you said in general, but that the single case of zeroing memory is sufficiently distinct from other use cases that it rarely becomes a problem. Changing one fill to another, maybe. But zero fills are a dime a dozen, and tend not to change to anything else.

Comment: I cannot see any reason to use memset in C++. `std::fill` works just as well and is less likely to break if the code changes. What is the advantage of memset?

Comment: @vsoftco: I suspect `std::fill` could be optimized out in the same situations. The compiler is going to try to save cycles when it can after all, and won't zero memory it knows it won't read again unless you force it to (e.g. by explicit zeroing using `volatile` qualifiers, or on Windows, by using `SecureZeroMemory`).

Comment: @NeilKirk: No advantage (unless the `std::fill` implementers were bad at their jobs and didn't use all the optimizations `memset` uses to minimize work for POD types; I doubt it, but stranger things have happend), but I tend to work in a mix of C and C++, and the benefits of `std::fill` aren't sufficient for me to use it (and potentially poison C code to require C++ when it wouldn't otherwise need it) by preference for something `memset` does equally well.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using the c++ array in the standard library. By simply changing initialization of the array from `int x[5] = {1,2,3,4,5}` to `std::array<int,5> x = {1,2,3,4,5}`. The beauty of using `std::array` is that it when compiled with the flag `-std=c++11` it will allow you assign the entire array to one value after initialization e.g. `x = {0};` essentially "clearing" your array. This simplifies your code and does not require you to use functions like `memset()`, `std::fill`, it even does away with for loops. It is widely recommended that you adopt the use of c++ standard container such as `std::vector` and `std::array` as they allow for much safer cleaner code with little or no performance overhead. To demonstrate using `std::array` I have written the code below which again should be compiled using the `-std=c++11` flag.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

int  main()
{
    // Declares an array of size 5 and of type int and intialises.
    std::array<int,5> x = {1,2,3,4,5};

    // Prints each element
    for (size_t i = 0; i < x.size() ; i++)
    {
        std::cout << x[i] << std::endl;
    }

    // Assigns each element to "0" or "Clearing the array"
    x = {0};

    // Prints each element
    for (size_t i = 0; i < x.size() ; i++)
    {
        std::cout << x[i] << std::endl;
    }
    std::cin.get();
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```